# How To Search Two Mysql tables Using Ones Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have tables like this

**mainTable**

```
Id | name | country
1  | John | 5
2  | Bill | 7
```

**categoriesTable**

```
other_table_id | category
1              | 6
1              | 12
```

My question is how can I say

```
SELECT id FROM mainTable 
WHERE country=5 
AND WHERE categoriesTable order_table_id=[**THE ID I JUST GOT FROM THE FIRST TABLE**] && category=6 || category=12
```

Then returns the number of records that match so in this case 1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't anyone learn how to write JOINs when they learn SQL?

```
SELECT m.id
FROM mainTable AS m
JOIN categoriesTable AS c ON c.other_table_id = m.id
WHERE c.category IN (6, 12)
AND m.country = 5
```